# saving blob in django creates a file with size 0

Tags: django, python-3.x

I post an audio blob to django using ajax, before posting I do

```
console.log(blob) 
//prints 
//Blob(262188) {size: 262188, type: "audio/wav"}
//size: 262188
//type: "audio/wav"
//__proto__: Blob
```

Inside the django view:

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

audio_data = request.FILES.get("recordedBlob", None)

print(type(audio_data)) #prints <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>

print(audio_data.size) #prints 262188

path = default_storage.save('audio/' + '123' + '.wav', ContentFile(audio_data.read()))
```

But when I open the audio file in my file system, it is size Zero Bytes.

Any idea how to save the blob correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was calling

```
print(len(audio_data.read()))
```

and it seems like calling .read() empties out the data. So taking this line away solved the problem.

Comment: I tried this method, but the received wav file is corrupted. I cant play them.

Comment: Can you put your code on github and share it?

Comment: Thanks, i created the following repository. There is two files, one for front which records the sound and a view file for processing. https://github.com/Keramatfar/django_sound_file

Comment: Actually, i can save the file on the server but i cant play them by players. Also i need to process the sound file but i cant read it by python and i get errors like this: Not an audio file.
Sound not read from sound file

Comment: Great to hear that